# Using pandas to categories text data in one column and have corresponding categories stated in the next column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

My excel spread sheet currently looks like this after inserting the new column "Expense" by using the code:

1. import pandas as pd
2. df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Mihir Patel\Project\Excel & CSV Stuff\June '20 CSVData.csv")
3. df_Expense = df.insert(2, "Expense", " ")
4. df.to_excel(r"C:\Users\Mihir Patel\Project\Excel & CSV Stuff\June '20 CSVData.xlsx", index=None, header=True)

[image]

So because the Description column contains the word "DRAKES" I can categories that expense as "Personal" which should appear in the Expense column next to it.

Similarly the next one down contains "Optus" is categorized as a mobile related expense so the word "Phone" should appear in the Expense column.

I have tried searching on Google and YouTube but I just can't seem to find an example for something like this.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using a while loop. I tried to use the method in quest's answer but I most likely didn't use it properly and kept getting an error. So I used a while loop to search through each individual cell in the "Description" column and categories it in the same row on the "Expense" column.

My solution using a while loop:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Mihir Patel\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\June '20 CSVData.csv")
df.insert(2, "Expenses", "")
description = "Description"
expense = "Expenses"
transfer = "Transfer"

i = -1 #Because I wanted python to start searching from index 0

while i < 296: #296 is the row where my data ends
    i = i + 1

    if "Drakes".upper() in df.loc[i, description]:
        df.loc[i, expense] = "Personal"

    if "Optus".upper() in df.loc[i, description]:
        df.loc[i, expense] = "Phone"

df.sort_values(by=["Expenses"], inplace=True)
df.to_excel("C:\\Users\\Mihir Patel\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject\\June '20 CSVData.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function which has all these rules and simply apply it. For ex.

```
def rules(x):
    if "DRAKES" in x.description:
        return "Personal"
    if "OPUS" in x.description:
        return "Mobile"

df["Expense"] = df.apply(lambda x: rules(x), axis=1)
```